# In which version of openssl is the pkcs8 v2 option introduced?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#8, pkcs#5, pkcs

In which version of openssl is the pkcs8 v2 option introduced?

Ex: openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -topk8 -v2 des3 -out enckey.pem

From which version of openssl does v2 of pkcs8 work by default?(Which uses the pkcs#5 v2.0)

Comment: The `-v2` option for `pkcs8` existed back in the year 2000, when OpenSSL 0.9.5a was released: [OpenSSL doc page for pkcs8 from Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20001020093418/http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html).  Hopefully you're not using a version older than that.  If so, good luck finding an earlier reference.

Comment: Further research looks like the `-v2` option of `pkcs8` was introduced in OpenSSL 0.9.4, August of 1999.